Ask for the asymptotic behaviour of a solution $f$ to Falkner-Skan Equations?
Assume that $0 < \beta < 2$, the Falkner-Skan equation is
$$
\begin{cases}
  f''' + ff'' + \beta(1-(f')²) = 0, &\text{and}\\
  f(0) = f'(0) = 0,\\ 
f'(\infty) = 1.
\end{cases} \label{1}\tag{FS}
$$
Known that $0 < f' < 1, f''>0$ in $(0,\infty)$, $f''(0) > 0$, ask for the asymptotic behaviour of a solution $f$ to \eqref{1}, does it satisfy
$$
  1-f'(\xi)=O\big(\xi^{-1}e^{-C_1\xi^2}\big),\quad f''(\xi)=O\big(\xi(1-f'(\xi))\big)=O\big(e^{-C_1\xi^2}\big),
$$
if it does, why?

In a first, rather coarse approximation for the behavior at infinity, for any solution actually satisfying the boundary conditions you get $f'(x)\approx 1$, thus $f(x)\approx x-c$ and the differential equation simplifies to
$$
f'''(x)+(x-c)f''(x)=0.
$$
This has a solution
$$
f''(x)=C\exp\left(-\frac12(x-c)^2\right)\sim C\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}2\right).
$$
Integrate that again, and again using partial integration, to get
$$
1-f'(\xi)=\int_\xi^\infty f''(x)\,dx=\frac C\xi \exp\left(-\frac{\xi^2}2\right)
-\int_\xi^\infty \frac{C}{x^2}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}2\right)\,dx
$$
The second term is asymptotically smaller (if only slightly) and thus subordinate to the first term.
Now above I set some terms as exactly equal that are only asymptotically so. This can be repaired by allowing some leeway in the constants, which results in the form of the asymptotic bounds
